# Javascript require(), how to include a simple require('something')

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, ofx

I need to use this library [banking.js](https://github.com/euforic/banking.js) which uses modules. I have downloaded RequireJS and I have been reading for hours, but I can't seem to find any tutorial that uses simply require('Module') like how it is suggested on the github page, they all use different kind of methods that pass anonymous functions (they didn't work for me either). 
I constantly get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "banking" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

I followed the documentation but nothing is working.

Comment: Are you using node? banking.js appears to require node.

Comment: I suppose banking.js is for Node.js only

Comment: No, requireJS is similar to the Node require() I believe, but for javascript

Comment: @RoudyTarabay They both make sure of a `require()` function, but not in a way that's really compatible with each other. The project also uses Node.js-specific APIs that aren't going to be available within a browser.

Comment: So this library cannot be used unless I want to use Node.js for server side stuff? I only care about parsing the ofx file into JSON on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS projects use the CommonJS (CJS) format for modules; RequireJS is mostly used for AMD modules with a few hacks to try to make the two interoperable.

You may want to look into [Browserify](http://browserify.org/); it will bundle CJS modules into a browser-includeable JS file, and provides some replacements for NodeJS core modules.

Comment: Did not work, but I gave up, I will try to find another solution. However Browserify is interesting. Thanks.